# Error in Github Action for Laravel / PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, laravel-8, github-actions

I have an error in my github action for my laravel unit/feature tests using PHPUnit. My tests are passing locally. This is the error:

```
1) Tests\Feature\ClientControllerTest::test_clients_index_page_is_rendered
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (SQL: alter table "users" add column "role_id" integer not null)
```

It could be that I'm not fully understanding the way the testing works, but I'm using an in-memory sqllite database for testing. I have a migration for the users table and then another migration that adds a role_id to the user table after a roles table is created.

Not understanding why the error is occurring during the test_clients_index_page_is_rendered test because the database should already be up and populated at that point.

I don't know if it's because the roles table is not populated with data, and it's a foreign key on the users table. I would think that would fail locally as well though because I'm still using the in-memory database. I have a seeder to populate the roles, but I'm not calling it from anywhere in my tests. Not sure if I need to be doing that, or where to do it?

Here is the test mentioned in the error:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ClientControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    protected $user;

    public function setup() :void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->user = User::factory()->create();
    }

    public function test_clients_index_page_is_rendered()
    {
        $this->actingAs($this->user);
        $response = $this->get('/clients');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

Here are the related migrations that I suppose could also be causing the problems:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
}
```

And then later the roles table is added, and then the foreignkey:

```
 Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignIdFor(Role::class)->after('password');
        });
```

I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot this issue as it's passing locally. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the full trace in case it helps:

```
1) Tests\Feature\ClientControllerTest::test_clients_index_page_is_rendered
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (SQL: alter table "users" add column "role_id" integer not null)

/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:705
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:665
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:495
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php:109
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:363
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:210
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:261
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/database/migrations/2022_01_01_222316_add_role_id_to_users_table.php:19
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:394
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:403
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:202
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:167
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:112
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:85
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:585
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:94
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php:40
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:93
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:37
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:653
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:136
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:298
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:121
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1005
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:299
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:94
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:186
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:263
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/PendingCommand.php:260
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/PendingCommand.php:413
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithConsole.php:66
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/RefreshDatabase.php:45
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/RefreshDatabase.php:20
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:122
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:91
/home/runner/work/momentum/momentum/tests/Feature/ClientControllerTest.php:19

Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL
```

**UPDATE**

Adding my user factory:

```
namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;


class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => $this->faker->firstName,
            'last_name' => $this->faker->lastName,
            'phone' => $this->faker->unique()->numerify('###-###-####'),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi', 
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
            'role_id' => rand(1,4)
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am not confused, the error is happening because you have populated data on the same table you are trying to add the `role_id`, so when you add the `not null` column, it will be `null` for the created rows, thus the error...

Comment: @matiaslauriti I added my user factory, which is populating the role_id. I think I'm doing it right, but really not sure. Obviously something isn't right or it would be working..

Comment: Why are you using `rand` instead of [`Role::factory()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-relationships-within-factories)? You are using `RefreshDatabase` so you should not have data.

Comment: @matiaslauriti - I was under the impression that I should use a seeder for my roles, since they are pre-defined values, not random data. I do have a roles seeder that I call on my local dev environment, but I don't know how to call a seeder in a test, or if that's what I should be doing. In my user factory, I'd like to get a random role id within the 4 available roles I have.

Comment: You should be seeding the data then, you can do so using [`$this->seed()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#running-seeders), but read the documentation that explains everything about it (for testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the stack trace, exception thrown during the migration step.

This happens because you adding `not null` column to your table, which generally impossible. SQLite don't know what value should be set to `role_id` for records that already in the table, so it prevents you from this operation.

You can either add default value to `role_id`, or move it to initial migration.